# awk script read line matching a pattern and result output with comma separated

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, cut

help with shell script to read pattern in comma separated line and end result output should again be in comma separated. In below eg, read line separated by commas and output only puppet strings again separated by commas.

```
echo "docker-one,puppet-one,puppet-two,docker-three,puppet-four" | script
```

output required:

```
docker-one,docker-three
```

Comment: Where's the code you've tried? this is fairly basic stuff...

Comment: IFS="," for v in $variable; do echo $v | grep -v puppet; done

Comment: Buti need the output to be comma separated

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Are you printing the docker fields because they contain docker or because they do not contain puppet? Please fix `output only puppet strings` to say whatever it is you really mean. Do you REALLY only have 1 line of input? Do you REALLY want it to be read from a pipe or do you want a script that can operate on a file of such lines or can it be a script that parses a value passed as an argument rather than from a pipe?

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
echo "docker-one,puppet-one,puppet-two,docker-three,puppet-four" | 
awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS=","} /puppet/'

puppet-one,puppet-two,puppet-four
```

for docker, and replacing the last comma

```
echo "docker-one,puppet-one,puppet-two,docker-three,puppet-four" | 
awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS=","} /docker/' | 
sed 's/,$/\n/'

docker-one,docker-three
```

or, if you meant **non puppet**

```
echo "docker-one,puppet-one,puppet-two,docker-three,puppet-four" | 
awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS=","} !/puppet/' | 
sed 's/,$/\n/'

docker-one,docker-three
```

Comment: sorry, expected output "docker-one,docker-three"

Comment: That would produce a comma with no subsequent newline at the end of the output if the last string didn't contain puppet.

Comment: When you produce text that doesn't end with a newline then it's no longer a POSIX "file" so what any subsequent command (e.g. sed) might do with that as input is undefined behavior so YMMV with trying to correct it with a pipe to another command.

Answer (score 2):

Using native `bash` regEx operator `~` and using `GNU paste` for `csv` formatting alone,

```
IFS="," read -ra myArray <<<"docker-one,puppet-one,puppet-two,docker-three,puppet-four"
for i in "${myArray[@]}";do [[ $i =~ ^puppet ]] && echo "$i" ; done | paste -sd ','
```

produces an output as

```
puppet-one,puppet-two,puppet-four
```

and for the other strings than the ones starting with `puppet`, do a negative regex match,

```
for i in "${myArray[@]}";do [[ ! $i =~ ^puppet ]] && echo "$i" ; done | paste -sd ','
docker-one,docker-three
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like one of these might be what you're looking for:

```
$ echo "docker-one,puppet-one,puppet-two,docker-three,puppet-four" |
awk -F, '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ /puppet/) printf "%s%s", (c++?FS:""), $i; print ""}'
puppet-one,puppet-two,puppet-four

$ echo "docker-one,puppet-one,puppet-two,docker-three,puppet-four" |
awk -F, '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i !~ /puppet/) printf "%s%s", (c++?FS:""), $i; print ""}'
docker-one,docker-three

$ echo "docker-one,puppet-one,puppet-two,docker-three,puppet-four" |
awk -F, '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ /docker/) printf "%s%s", (c++?FS:""), $i; print ""}'
docker-one,docker-three
```

Answer (score 0):

Using tr, grep, and paste:

```
$ echo "docker-one,puppet-one,puppet-two,docker-three,puppet-four" \
       | tr , '\n' | grep -v puppet | paste -s -d , -
docker-one,docker-three
```